# Changing an PL/SQL Block into a Procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, dynamic-sql

I have this PL/SQL block that creates a view everytime I run it. 
I want to change it into a stored procedure with the name "VIEW_PROC" so I will only have to run the proc everytime I want to create the view. 
How do I do it?

```
set serveroutput on
declare 
  compte number;

  DQEntity varchar2(50);
  DynSQL varchar2(4000);
  finale varchar2(4000);
  v1 varchar2(40):='''DD-MM-YY''';
  createview varchar2(4000) :=  'CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE EDITIONABLE VIEW "DV2_OBIDMT"."F_GENERAL_DATA_QLTY3" ("SRC_SYS_ID", "SOFT_RULE_NAME", "ENTITY_NAME", "DATE_", "PASSES", "FAILS") AS ('; 

begin 

  select COUNT(*) into compte
      from DV2_OBIADM.IM_LUT_ENTITY_SOFT_RULES;

  for ins in (select ENTITY_NAME as Q1
                  from DV2_OBIADM.IM_LUT_ENTITY_SOFT_RULES  

              ) 
  loop

    DQEntity:= ins.Q1;

    DynSQL := DynSQL || 'select 
                                SRC.SRC_SYS_ID,
                                EN.SOFT_RULE_NAME,
                                EN.ENTITY_NAME,
                                (to_date(to_char(SRC.LDTS,'||v1||'))) as date_,
                                sum(case when SRC.QLTY_TEST= '||'''Pass'''||' then 1 else 0 end) as Passes, 
                                sum(case when SRC.QLTY_TEST= '||'''Fail'''||' then 1 else 0 end) as Fails
                                from "DV2_OBIADM".IM_LUT_ENTITY_SOFT_RULES EN, ' ||DQEntity|| '  SRC
                                WHERE EN.ENTITY_NAME = ''' || DQEntity || '''
                                GROUP BY SRC.SRC_SYS_ID, EN.ENTITY_NAME, EN.SOFT_RULE_NAME,(to_date(to_char(SRC.LDTS,'||v1||'))) ' ;
    compte := compte -1; 

    if compte >= 1 then 

      DynSQL := DynSQL ||chr(13)||chr(10)|| '  UNION ALL ';
    end if; 

  end loop;
  finale := createview || DynSQL;
  finale := finale|| ')';

  execute immediate finale;
end;
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Replace `declare` keyword with `create or replace procedure VIEW_PROC is `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code for creating your stored procedure:

```
create or replace procedure VIEW_PROC is

compte number;

DQEntity varchar2(50);
DynSQL varchar2(4000);
finale varchar2(4000);
v1 varchar2(40):='''DD-MM-YY''';
createview varchar2(4000) :=  'CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE EDITIONABLE VIEW "DV2_OBIDMT"."F_GENERAL_DATA_QLTY3" ("SRC_SYS_ID", "SOFT_RULE_NAME", "ENTITY_NAME", "DATE_", "PASSES", "FAILS") AS 

  ('; 


begin 

select COUNT(*) into compte
    from DV2_OBIADM.IM_LUT_ENTITY_SOFT_RULES;

for ins in (
select ENTITY_NAME as Q1
    from DV2_OBIADM.IM_LUT_ENTITY_SOFT_RULES  

) loop

DQEntity:= ins.Q1;

DynSQL := DynSQL || 'select 
                            SRC.SRC_SYS_ID,
                            EN.SOFT_RULE_NAME,
                            EN.ENTITY_NAME,
                            (to_date(to_char(SRC.LDTS,'||v1||'))) as date_,
                            sum(case when SRC.QLTY_TEST= '||'''Pass'''||' then 1 else 0 end) as Passes, 
                            sum(case when SRC.QLTY_TEST= '||'''Fail'''||' then 1 else 0 end) as Fails
                            from "DV2_OBIADM".IM_LUT_ENTITY_SOFT_RULES EN, ' ||DQEntity|| '  SRC
                            WHERE EN.ENTITY_NAME = ''' || DQEntity || '''
                            GROUP BY SRC.SRC_SYS_ID, EN.ENTITY_NAME, EN.SOFT_RULE_NAME,(to_date(to_char(SRC.LDTS,'||v1||'))) ' ;
compte := compte -1; 

     if compte >= 1 then 

        DynSQL := DynSQL ||chr(13)||chr(10)|| '  UNION ALL ';
   end if; 

end loop;
finale := createview || DynSQL;
finale := finale|| ')';

execute immediate finale;

end VIEW_PROC;
```

At the beginning you had to add `create or replace procedure VIEW_PROC is`, remove `declare` and add the procedure name `VIEW_PROC` after `END` keyword at the end.